# Adding an array of objects to another array in codeigntier PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object, codeigniter-2

im using codeigntier framework im trying to solve a problem to do with retrieving information from a database for example:

model.php:

```
public function read(){
   $query = $this->db->get('table');
   return $query->result();
}
```

controller.php:

```
  public function doSomething () {
       $exampleArray['name'] = "Bob's Database";
       $getModel = $this->load->model('model','getData');
       $modelData = $this->getData->read();
       // i want to assign the the $modelData to a array element like so
       $exampleArray['modelData'] = $modelData // here's where im stuck :(
}
```

thanks for your help!!
p.s. this is not an error, its just a question :)

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to access `$exampleArray` outside of that method, you'll have to do one of two things:

**a)** set it as a class variable

```
class MyClass {
    public $exampleArray;
    .
    .
    . 
}
```

then refer to it using

```
$this->exampleArray['index']
```

or **b)** pass it by reference into your `doSomething()` function:

```
public function doSomething(&$exampleArray) { ... }
```

The php manual has a section on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) that should help you better understand this.

Comment: i think you got me wrong, but nice answer, im not talking about scope here, im trying to assign the array of objects that i get from my model to the $exampleArray['modelData'] variable, i was wondering if i did it right on my code!

Comment: Yes, you did. After the assignment, use `var_dump($exampleArray)` to verify. (You may want to echo `<pre>` tags around your `var_dump()` to make it clearer in your browser.)